# Function Tooltip it doesn;t work

Tags: jquery-ui

Why my tooltip not working :(? I'm checking it 2 hours and i don't have any mind.

```
<div class="changebk">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
               <a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="opis"></a>
              <img src="img/facebook.png">
        </li >
        <li class="box">
              <a href="http://www.twitter.com"></a>
              <img src="img/twiiter.png">
        </li>
        <li class="box">
            <a href="http://www.direction-code.pl"></a>
            <img src="img/logom.png">
        </li>
      </ul>


$('.changebk a').tooltip({
      content: '<img src="img/logom.png" alt="Here it;s me">'
    }); // koniectoltip
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. We don't even know whether you have included all the required scripts

Answer (score -1):

you should add title in your html code inside

```
<div class="changebk">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
               <a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="opis" title=""></a>
              <img src="img/facebook.png">
        </li >
        <li class="box">
              <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title=""></a>
              <img src="img/twiiter.png">
        </li>
        <li class="box">
            <a href="http://www.direction-code.pl" title=""></a>
            <img src="img/logom.png">
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

see the example here https://jsfiddle.net/ct6vrao8/